# Angular 2: Length validation not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular-validation

I am trying to simply replicate the walkthrough from the Angular website but cannot get length validation to work:

```
<input 
  style="display:inline-block;min-width:150px" 
  class="form-input" 
  id="phone"
  required 
  minlength="4" 
  maxlength="24"
  type="number" 
  name="phone" 
  [(ngModel)]="client.phone" 
  #phone="ngModel" /> 

  <!-- required works, minlength and maxlength always false -->
  {{ phone.hasError('required') }} {{ phone.hasError('minlength') }} {{ phone.hasError('maxlength') }}

<div *ngIf="phone.errors && (phone.dirty || phone.touched)"
   class="alert alert-danger">
  <div [hidden]="!phone.errors.required">
    Name is required
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="!phone.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="!phone.errors.maxlength">
    Name cannot be more than 24 characters long.
  </div>
</div>
```

I must be missing something simple, but for some reason the `required` validation changes depending on input, but both `minlength` and `maxlength` are always `false` regardless of how long my input is.

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeric-formatter this will prevent users input exceeding the digit count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because number type doesnt have length property

[image]

There is a bug for this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15053

You can work around it like:

```
[ngModel]="client.phone" (ngModelChange)="client.phone = $event + ''"
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ESalMtXLhxxSdAjzP514?p=preview)**

**Update**

Since in **4.2.0-beta.0** (2017-05-04) were introduced min and max validators so you can have a look https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15813/commits/52b0ec8062381e7285b5f66aa83008edfbf02af3

Comment: I knew I was missing something.  Thank you!

Comment: What if i don't want the same on the submit not on change?